# Is it okay to import a similar class into a helper module, then into a main module (without using it in the helper)?

Tags: python-import, fractions

Python version: 3.10.0

I am working on a tooling set for some LaTex formatting with mathematics content. As part of this, I would have created a class for fractions that are not being simplified, yet still have most of the functionality of the `Fraction` class from the `fractions` module. This is a completely custom and unique class.

`fraction_tools.py`

```py
class UnsimplifiedFraction:
    # A completely custom class, not inheriting from Fraction, that has similar functionality.
    # i.e. has addition, subtraction, multiplication and division but **does not simplify**.
```

In another, more functional, file I am utilising these fractions within a more complex construction:

`do_stuff.py`

```py
from .fraction_tools import UnsimplifiedFraction
...
...
        result = [
            [
                UnsimplifiedFraction(a1_1, FRAC),
                UnsimplifiedFraction(a1_2, FRAC),
            ],
            [
                UnsimplifiedFraction(a2_1, FRAC),
                UnsimplifiedFraction(a2_2, FRAC),
            ]
        ]
...
...
```

However, within the `do_stuff` (and many other) file(s) I have other requirements to use the `Fraction` class as well as the `UnsimplifiedFraction` class.
It seems more reader friendly to include the import once in the `fraction_tools.py` file, but `Fraction` will not actually be used within that file (leading to a linting error).

**Is there a preference between `from fractions import Fraction` in multiple modules, or importing it once in `fraction_tools.py` and then `from .fraction_tools import Fraction, UnsimplifiedFraction`?**
i.e.:

### Option a

`fraction_tools.py`

```py
from fractions import Fraction  # linting error for unused import


class UnsimplifiedFraction:
    # A completely custom class, not inheriting from Fraction, that has similar functionality.
    # i.e. has addition, subtraction, multiplication and division but **does not simplify**.
```

`do_stuff.py`

```py
from .fraction_tools import Fraction, UnsimplifiedFraction
...
...
# code requiring both Fraction and UnsimplifiedFraction
...
...
```

### Option b

`fraction_tools.py`

```py
class UnsimplifiedFraction:
    # A completely custom class, not inheriting from Fraction, that has similar functionality.
    # i.e. has addition, subtraction, multiplication and division but **does not simplify**.
```

`do_stuff.py`

```py
from fractions import Fraction  # not as nice to read and required in multiple files
from .fraction_tools import UnsimplifiedFraction
...
...
# code requiring both Fraction and UnsimplifiedFraction
...
...
```

I have considered updating the `UnsimplifiedFraction` class for this specific instance, but two problems exist:

- I am not sure how to approach this in the timescale available.
- The general concept is still a question for me; is it a good practice to import similar pre-existing classes into an overall helper module and then import from that helper, or should the import happen in multiple places?

Either code *works*, I just don't know which is preferred or advised (against!).